# Working with Int field and operations

Tags: haskell

I have an expression of type `([(Int,Int->Int->Int)],[Int])`, where first `Int` in `(Int,Int->Int->Int)` is priority of the operation. So it may look like this: `([(0,+),(1,mod),(2,^)],[16,5,2,3])` and expresses `16 + 5 mod 2 ^ 3`. The priority of those operations is the same as in Haskell. Is there even a way forward to compute the expression?

Comment: Hint: What should the algorithm do when the first list is empty and the second has one element? What should it do when the first list has one element and the second list has two? Which cases have not been covered by the previous two cases and what should the algorithm do in those cases?

Comment: Sounds like a pattern matching. I still have a bit problem to execute the operator in the right place, eg that mod between 5 and 2.

Comment: This looks as a nice exercise, but here on SO we usually don't solve those, since they are too broad. We can help on specific points, though, once you have a reasonable attempt.

Comment: I was supposed to convert string of numbers and operations to a result, eg. "3 + 5 * 44" as an input and 223 as an output. This is where I got stuck, but mayby I took a bad road.

Comment: Most certainly did you take a bad road. Your data structure is not very well suited for your task. It would be better to have a tree-like structure that represents arithmetic expressions better.

Comment: The real question should be "how do I parse a string expression like `3 + 5 * 44` into a tree like `Node + (Leaf 3) (Node * (Leaf 5) (Leaf 44))`; such a tree is almost trivially evaluated, once the hard work of parsing the original string is done.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, now i have it (the tree way). It's sometimes difficult for me to take the right approach to the situation.